# ¿Cómo puedo añadir más de una coordenada?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

He intentado añadir más de una coordenada al código JavaScript, pero cada vez que lo intento desaparece el mapa, me gustaría agregar más de una sola coordenada.

```
function iniciarMap(){
  var coord = {lat:10.9897276 ,lng: -74.8045349};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 5,
    center: coord
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coord,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: Podrías poner tu código para agregar más coordenadas?

Answer (score -1):

te dejo un ejemplo de la librería original:

https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

también un link a la documentación.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

Saludos.